# Symfony2 Exception Catching confusion

Tags: php, symfony, exception, authentication

I am trying to learn Symfony 2 and have run into a weird issue with exception catching that I don't understand.

I am trying to implement a modified version of [the API Authentication](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html) on the Symfony site but using $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] instead (as this is where the IIS passes the Windows Authentication user to PHP).

When I follow the tutorial, there are both `UsernameNotFoundException` and `AuthenticationException` that can be thrown, but when I use then I get a `BadCredentialsException` (A Token was not found in the SecurityContext.).

I can see the other exceptions being thrown in my logs, but they appear to be caught by the Kernel and code execution continues until the token is requested and doesn't exist, which throws the `BadCredentialsException` which isn't caught and finally errors the system.

As far as I can tell:

1. In a `PreAuthenticationInterface`, I attempt to check the username in $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] with a known user.
2. Username isn't found (actually doesn't match strings - I haven't started to integrate a database yet)
3. A `UsernameNotFoundException` is thrown by me and is caught by the Kernel. Since throwing an exception works like `return`, none of the code after it executes and nothing is returned.
4. Since nothing is returned, no Authentication Token is created.
5. The firewall tries to get the (non-existent) token from the security context, which it can't so it throws a `BadCredentialsException`.
6. The `BadCredentialsException` is not caught, a kernel.exception event is finally fired and Symfony returns a 500 error.

That's all well and good, but I'd actually like to respond to a `UsernameNotFoundException` and display an informative message to my users.

I've tried creating a custom EventListener, but I can only hook onto the `kernel.exception` event, and that doesn't fire on caught exceptions, so I only see the `BadCredentialsException`.

So how do I actually respond to the `UsernameNotFoundException` or `AuthenticationException` and not have them caught and hidden?

Comment: You need to use try/catch blocks around the code which calls your function that throws the error. Deal with responding how you want in your catch statement.

Answer (score 0):

BTW: You should not access $_SERVER directly. Instead you should use Request object. It contains $_SERVER values as well. (Details: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html).

Are you trying to tell to user one of:

- Bad password
- Bad username

?

You should avoid it. *UsernameNotFoundException* is for provider staff. If you return exact information what's wrong you will give information "I have/or not this user". In case of email as a username you will expose them to the world. Unauthorize with proper HTTP status code should be enough (this should be done for you by: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/ExceptionListener.php)